# Доступ для разработчиков на боевой сервер

Tags: apache, права, linux

Есть группа разработчиков (три человека), которым надо дать доступ на сервер, чтобы они могли править сайт на лету (недочеты в стилях и прочие мелочи). Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще доступ на работающий сервер разработчикам давать не надо, это чревато

1. падениями сервера в самые неподходящие моменты,
2. утратой контроля версий, если менять будут на лету,
3. утечкой закрытых данных.

Всегда лучше, если построением сборок и заливкой их на сервер занимается отдельный человек.  А так подход простой:

- создать отдельную группу,
- сделать эту группу владельцем всех возможно изменяемых файлов,
- выставить права на чтение, запись и исполнение для группы на эти файлы.

Comment: Совершенно согласен с тем, что разрабов пущать на рабочий сервер низя :) Пусть работают с копиями и не ленятся делать бекапы

Answer (score 1):

На вашем месте сделал бы для девелоперов виртуальную машину в локальной сети и в зависимости от конкретной разработки (веб-разработки или С) дал бы проброс портов на неё